# Swift: Checking Prefix with Regex

Tags: swift, regex

I am attempting to check if a string begins with a text that follows a regex pattern. Is there a way to do so using `string.hasPrefix()`?

My implementation so far:

```
let pattern = "[Ff][Yy][Ii](.)?"
let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])

if firstRowText.hasPrefix(regex) { //Cannot convert value of type NSRegularExpression to String

}
```

Comment: You can use `^` in your regex to specify the start of line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a regex using [`range(of:options:range:locale:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1417348-range) passing the `.regularExpression` option with [`.anchored`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsregularexpression.matchingoptions/1410858-anchored) option:

```
if firstRowText.range(of: "[Ff][Yy][Ii]", options: [.regularExpression, .anchored]) != nil {...}
```

The `.anchored` option makes the regex engine search for a match at the start of the string only.

To make your regex match in a case insensitive way, you may pass another option alongside the current ones, [`.caseInsensitive`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/compareoptions/1412382-caseinsensitive), and use a shorter regex, like `"FYI"`:

```
if firstRowText.range(of: "FYI", options: [.regularExpression, .anchored, .caseInsensitive]) != nil {
```

See the [Swift online demo](https://rextester.com/RWGYPK36314).

Note that you may also use an inline modifier option `(?i)` to set case insensitivity:

```
"(?i)FYI"
```